# about display messages in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I add new module in magento 1.7.0.2,everything is ok.I click add to cart can't display success messages,but the product is ok in my cart.When I click on another page,the messages appears.

app/design/frontend/default/f001/layout/printer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default> 
        <reference name="right"> 
            <block type="printer/finder" name="product.finder" before="-" template="printer/finder.phtml" /> 
        </reference> 
    </default> 
    <printer_finder_result>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="printer/finder_result" name="product.finder.result" template="printer/finder/result.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </printer_finder_result>
</layout>
```

app/code/local/HB/Printer/Block/Finder/Result.php

```
class HB_Printer_Block_Finder_Result extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $storeID = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $printerID = $this->getRequest()->getParam('modelId'); 
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        $collection->getSelect()
                   ->joinInner(
                       array('e2' => 'printer_applicable_product'),
                       'e2.product_id = e.entity_id'
                   )
                   ->where('e2.printer_id = ?', $printerID)
                   ;

        $this->setProductCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $toolbar = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar', microtime())
            ->setCollection($this->getProductCollection());

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', microtime());
        $toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        $this->getProductCollection()->load();

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }
}
```

app/code/local/HB/Printer/controllers/FinderController.php

```
class HB_Printer_FinderController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('Products Finder'));     
        $this->loadLayout();     
        $this->renderLayout();

    }

    public function resultAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('Printer Applicable Products'));
        $this->loadLayout();     
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Why not display messages in current page.How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to init needed layout messages through Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_initLayoutMessages()

Example:

```
public function resultAction()
{
    $this->_title($this->__('Printer Applicable Products'));
    $this
        ->loadLayout()
        ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
        ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session')
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

You need to init a session model that contains needed messages.

Also keep in mind that **printer/finder/result.phtml** should contain

```
$this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml()
```